# Prove Complex Number $Im(z_1\bar z_2 ) = |z_1||z_2|$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from an old exam, can someone please help me show equivalence?

Let $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb C$  be non-zero complex numbers. Show that
$$Im(z_1\bar z_2 ) =  |z_1||z_2|$$

if and only if

$$[\arg(z_1)]-[\arg(z_2)] = {(4n+1)\pi/2, n \in \mathbb Z}$$

Comment: The question is not to show "LHS=RHS", but to show an equivalence. So you have basically two implications to prove. Did you try something ?

Comment: I did but went off completely on a tangent.

Comment: Note that with $w = z_1\bar z_2$ this reduces to the question “when is $\operatorname{Im}(w) = |w|$?”

Answer (score 0):

Note that the condition has to read $\ldots + \ldots = \ldots$. With minus you’ll see that the first statement is symmetric, but the condition is not. And for an example: Take $z_1=\exp(\pi(1/2+1/3)\mathrm i) = -1/2\sqrt{3} + 1/2\mathrm i$ and $z_0=\exp(1/3\mathrm i) = 1/2+1/2\sqrt{3}\mathrm i$. Then $\arg(z_1)-\arg(z_2) = \pi/2$, but $z_1z_2 = -1/2\sqrt{3}-1/2\mathrm i$.

Then:

If $r_i=|z_i|$ and $\phi_i=\arg z_i$ then by the formula of Euler we get
$$ z_i = r_i\exp(\phi_i\mathrm i) $$
Then
$$ z_1z_2 = r_1r_2\exp((\phi_1+\phi_2)\mathrm i) $$
Then by Euler you want to investigate: When is
$$ r_1r_2\sin(\phi_1+\phi_2) = r_1r_2 $$
From this it is easy to prove equivalence to $$\phi_1+\phi_2 = \pi/2 + k2\pi$$
for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.